# Using Highmaps with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Building with React... Trying to use outside method called on button click

Attempting to set mappoints to invisible. I have tried using:
.hide()
.setVisible
and using .update() to set 'visible' to false

I am able to reference the chart and the mappoint using the included definition in the package markdown:

```
        let chart = this.refs.chart.getChart();
```

and in my render:

```
        <ReactHighmaps config={config} ref="chart" />
```

Attempted:

> 1. chart.series[2].event.update({visible: false}) >> Error: Highchart.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of
>      undefined
> 2. chart.plotOptions.mappoint.events.hide() >> TypeError: Cannot read property 'mappoint' of undefined
> 3. chart.series[2].setVisible(false, true) >> No Error in Console but nothing happens
> 4. chart.series[2].hide() >> No Error in Console but nothing happens And a few other variations.
> 5. ReactHighmaps.Highcharts.hide(chart.series[0]) >> Error that this isn't a function

There is a lot going on for me to make a JSbin...

Testing in Chrome

When I am inspecting the console.log of the mappoints I see that the method .setVisible() project path is:
.proto.proto.proto.setVisible

chart configuration (options):

```
        const config = {
        title: {
            text: 'ZCTA with Metric Data'
        },

        chart: {
            height: '600 px',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: 'silver',
            borderRadius: 3,
            shadow: true
        },
        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            map: {
                showInLegend: false
            },
            mappoint: {
                showInLegend: false,


            },
            mapline: {
                enabledMouseTracking: false,
                showInLegend: false

            }
        },
        series: [{
            mapData: MapData,
            name: 'test',
            data: County,
            joinBy: ['fips', 'code'],
            animation: true,
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b>'
            },
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 0.2,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    borderWidth: 0.5
                },
                select: {
                    color: 'yellow'
                }
            },
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer'
        },
        {
            type: 'mapline',
            name: 'State borders',
            data: lines,
            color: 'black',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    borderWidth: 0.5
                }
            },
            allowPointSelect: false
        },

        {
            type: 'mappoint',
            name: 'zcta',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1],
            data: Data,
            boostThreshold: 500,


        }]
```

For component render:

```
           <ReactHighmaps config={config} ref="chart" />
```

Any suggestions?

> Using React, Highcharts, and React-Highcharts (npm)

Comment: In standard Highcharts library this code works: `chart.series[2].hide()`

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/s9ocLnbd/

Are you sure that `chart.series[2]` is referencing the right series? Please provide the code of your chart's options.

Comment: @KamilKulig I added the code for the config. When I console.log(chart.series[2]) I get the correct series. I am thinking of approaching this through having the options part of the React State constructor, but am still trying to map that out in my head as I am struggling to think about how to follow react best practices but also not be inefficient by causing too many re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get any Highcharts(Highmaps) API methods to work, but was able to drill down to update the state object.

This led me to Redux as a state management tool because I realize it would be better to have this controlled in an application state versus React component.

Here is my action and reducer:

```
export const SHOW_POINTS = 'SHOW_POINTS'

export function showPoints(configuration){
  return {
    type: SHOW_POINTS,
    payload: configuration
 };
}



const PointsMapConfig = (state = initialState, action) => {
 switch (action.type){
   case SHOW_POINTS:
  return console.log(state.mapConfig.series[2]), { ...state,
    mapConfig: {
    series: [
      ...state.mapConfig.series.filter((el, index) => index !== 2), {
        ...state.mapConfig.series[2],
        visible: true
      }
    ]
  }
  }
    default:
  return state;
}
 }

 export default PointsMapConfig
```

onClick access with mapDispatchToProps:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({
    showPoints: showPoints
   }, dispatch);
 }

<Buttons style="success" classN="btn btn-secondary" text="test" onButtonClick={()=> this.props.showPoints( )} />
```